# Remote Desktop - Does leaving a session open slow down the server?

Tags: windows, performance, remote-desktop, rdp, session

Like many other development teams, we don't do a good job of signing out after an RDP session. I am trying to convince the team that it's important to use the "Sign Out" feature to close the session. It's my understanding that "Disconnect" or clicking the `[X]` leaves a session open...

Is the performance of a windows server affected by leaving sessions open? What other issues could arise from this?

Comment: All sessions requre at least some memory that must be maintained even if the session goes dormant. This is used to reinstate the sesion once a reconnect occurs.  That session can be huge, depending upon what was occurring in the session.  While it will eventually be rolled out to cache, it is still part of the virtual memory managed by the system.  Another concern might be that opened sessions may be holding locks preventing other things from occuring.  Simple case: Excel file being opened in a session; nobody can access it appropriately.  Resourcce locking should be avoided; signoff helps.

Answer (score 2):

Will it slow the server down? Possibly. A disconnected session still consumes resources.

The larger implication is the potential security ramifications of leaving an unattended session running on the server. For that reason alone I would strongly encourage the practice of logging out of the session.